# Do try's only work with terminating exceptions?

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

Try/Catch only works with terminating exceptions right?  This shows that 1/0 is a terminating error.

```
try { 1/0 } catch { 'term' }

term
```

But if I run the following code in a script, the script continues to run, so 1/0 is not really terminating?  I would think if 1/0 were terminating, the 'hi' would never print:

```
1/0
'hi'
```

Returns:

```
Attempted to divide by zero.
At C:\users\admin\test.ps1:1 char:1
+ 1/0
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

hi
```

EDIT:

See Mark Wragg's comment starting with "Consider that a statement..." on what a "statement terminating" exception is.  Basically the code in the one command doesn't finish, but the rest of the script does.

Comment: try `try { 1/0;'hi' } catch { 'term' }`. What is your `$ErrorActionPreference`?

Comment: I fail to see what failed in your example and am unable to replicate.

Comment: See: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  I would think if 1/0 was terminating, the 'hi' would never print.

Comment: @js2010 Your two code blocks do not match.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I am showing that the try works with 1/0, which is supposed to only work with terminating errors.

Comment: Now your question is confusing.  What behavior are you expecting versus what you get?  Your second codeblock of `test.ps1` **_does not match_** your example block.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I am expecting the 'hi' not to run.

Comment: I think i've made your question a bit clearer. It's actually a good question imho, as I had no idea there were statement vs script terminating errors before seeing this.

Comment: @MarkWragg hmm I don't really get what a statement terminating error is, except that it works with try/catch.

Comment: Consider that a statement (e.g any command you run) has its own internal code. Obviously 0/1 is quite a simple example, but `Get-ChildItem` will be doing lots of things. If `Get-ChildItem` returned a non-terminating error, something went wrong but its continuing with whatever else it had to do. If it had a problem that caused a statement terminating error, then `Get-ChildItem` would stop what its doing, but allow the script to continue (e.g any further commands would run). If `Get-ChildItem` had a problem that caused a script terminating error, the script would stop after that error.

Comment: @MarkWragg Ok, thanks.

Comment: @MarkWragg That makes me think of get-itemproperty when Netbeans is installed.  Netbeans puts in an invalid registry nomodify value under the uninstall area.  It makes get-itemproperty stop listing the rest of the registry values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GitHub issue](http://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) that [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) provided gives you the answer you are looking for.

It seems in PowerShell there are two types of terminating errors:

- Statement teminating errors
- Script terminating errors

There are also non-terminating errors.

My understanding is that when a non-terminating error occurs, the current statement outputs an error but continues to execute. When a statement terminating error occurs, an error is output and that statement terminates, but the script then continues to execute any further statements. When a script terminating error occurs the script stops at that error.

`1/0` is a statement terminating error, so it triggers the `catch` in a `try`..`catch` (where a non-terminating error wouldn't) but does not stop the script executing.

`Throw` creates a script terminating error.

It seems if you set `$ErrorActionPreference = Stop` then statement terminating errors become script terminating errors.

Example:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

1/0
'hi'
```

Result:

```
1/0
'hi'
Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:4 char:1
+ 1/0
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException


~>
```